# Google Sheets - calculating range based based upon variable criteria, with added multiplication

Tags: excel, google-sheets, conditional-statements

Working from this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aiZzzOFzPDrw_siMhL8XiNIp3q7f8nz58HvwBKn14uA/edit?usp=sharing

Trying to calculate sum of a column where value in another col is true: this works well, like this:
=SUMIF($B$5:$B$17,"NY",G5:G17)

I'd like to be able to calculate this but, also multiply the range in question by another variable, in column C (i.e. the "rate"), so that I get the sum of each number of hours in column G done by the resources in Col A, multiplied by the rate charged for each resource.

this obviously doesn't work, but this is the type of thing I'm looking for: =SUMIF($B$5:$B$17,"NY",G5:G17*(Corresponding value in Col C))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS will only accept a range so I don't think you can do it that way. The alternative is to use SUMPRODUCT.

In Google sheets:

```
=sumproduct((B5:B17="NY"),C5:C17,G5:G17)
```

Excel is slightly more picky: you have to coerce the inner bracket to a number, either

```
=sumproduct(--(B5:B17="NY"),C5:C17,G5:G17)
```

or

```
=sumproduct((B5:B17="NY")*C5:C17*G5:G17)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :-)